# WebApi bind body to Json dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I'm trying to create a WebApi action method with the following signature:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public object Execute([FromUri] string command, [FromUri] string method, [FromBody] IDictionary<string, JToken> arguments)
```

However, when I hit this method with requests, arguments never binds correctly (the two URI fields do). The ModelState shows a Json.NET parse error at the first character. I've tried request bodies that look like: `id=50` and `arguments={ "id": 50 }`. How do I have to formulate my request to allow WebApi to correctly bind my parameters?

Comment: Dictionaries consist of keyValuePairs, thus in the json world an array of objects, each having a Key and Value property, so IDictionary<string,int> binding requries json something like `arguments=[{Key:"id",Value:50},{Key:"another",Value:100}]`.  Might be off slightly, if you serialized a Dictionary as a JSON object you'd see what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the "id=" or "arguments=" in the request body. You should be able to just send something that looks like this:

```
{"key1": 4, "key2": 50, "key3": {"member1": "value"}}
```

and have it work. The Dictionary would then contain key1: a JValue with value 4, key2: a JValue with value 50, key3: a JObject with a member1 member with value "value".

Comment: Do AJAX libraries like JQuery and YUI support posting data in this format?