# How do I pass variable number of arguments to GET in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

public HttpResponseMessage Get( string where_name, 
                                IndexFieldsModel index_fields = null )

public class IndexFieldsModel
{
    public List<IndexFieldModel> Fields { get; set; }
}

public class IndexFieldModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is my API.  My problem is the index_fields is a collection of name value pairs, which is optional and variable length.  The thing is I don't know the names that will be passed to my GET method ahead of time.  An example call is:
     `/api/workitems?where_name=workitem&foo=baz&bar=yo`

Is IModelBinder the way to go here, or is there a simpler approach?  If it's IModelBinder how do I iterate through the names?  I went here to see an example of IModelBinder:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api
But I don't see a way to iterate through the names and pick out "foo" and "bar".

I tried changing index_fields to `Dictionary<string, string>` and no IModelBinding but that did nothing: index_fields was null.  When I'm doing IModelBinder and debugging my IModelBinder.BindModel routine, if I drill down into the ModelBindingContext object, I can see the "foo" and "bar" values in the `System.Web.Http.ValueProviders.Providers.QueryStringValueProvider`, but I don't know how to use that.  I tried creating a QueryStringValueProvider from scratch but it takes an HttpActionContext.  Again, I don't see a way to iterate through the keys to get "foo" and "bar".

BTW: I'm using VS2012

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486763/webapi-bind-body-to-json-dictionary

Comment: @DavidTansey I think `[FromBody]` is not relevant for GET requests

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply iterate through the query parameters

```
public ActionResult Method()
{
    foreach(string key in Request.QueryString) 
    {
        var value = Request.QueryString[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great, though I did have to use `Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs`.  There was no `Request.QueryString`.  Thanks!  (I would vote up your answer but I don't have enough reputation - sorry)