# C# Web Api (Non MVC) Dictionary parameters

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, web, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a Web Api that will be used by many websites / apps.

The Api takes dictionary as parameter as it will be dynamic.

C# Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public Dictionary<string, string> ApiTest(Dictionary<string, string> parameters )
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dic_data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> tmp in parameters)
        {
            dic_data[tmp.Key] = tmp.Value;
        }

    return dic_data;
}
```

Ajax Call to Method:

*Please note i left out contentType: "application/json" as it complains about it being including with CORS allowed*

```
var data = {"parameters":{"product_id":"1","product_model":"HFJ5G1.5","product_type":"plat","product_return":"graviteits"}};
//var data = {AlbumName: "Dirty Deeds",Songs:[ { SongName: "Problem Child"},{ SongName: "Squealer"}]};
var parameters = {};
parameters['1'] = 10;
parameters['2'] = 11;
$.ajax({
    type :'POST',
    url : 'http://localhost:8082/api/WebController/ApiTest/',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: parameters ,

    success : function(data) {
    console.log(data);
```

I have tried Binding the parameter as well:

```
public class myParameters
{
    public Dictionary<string,string> parameters { get; set; }
}
public Dictionary<string, string> ApiTest(myParameters parameters )
```

Still no luck.

On the browser console, I just keep receiving back "{}" from the API.

I have looked at many examples but none seem to help. I'm still very new to C# so some of the comments and answers was just above me (like the ModelBinder stuff)

[Passing List of KeyValuePair or IDictionary to Web Api Controller from Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553561/passing-list-of-keyvaluepair-or-idictionary-to-web-api-controller-from-javascrip)

[Method with Dictionary Parameter in Asp.Net Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950351/method-with-dictionary-parameter-in-asp-net-web-api)

[WebApi bind body to Json dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486763/webapi-bind-body-to-json-dictionary)

[Deserialize JSON into dictionary in Web Api controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988273/deserialize-json-into-dictionary-in-web-api-controller)

**UPDATE**:

After a few more hours of searching, i decided to make a "local" call to the API from the same site that hosts the API. 
I was then able to put in place contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', which had no problems with sending parsing JSON post object into Dictionary parameter :-(

So now my search continues of contentType + C# Api + Dictionary + CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS was enabled on the server. With simple binding parameters like strings it worked fine Crossdomain. Dictionary where is failed.

However i had to go one step further on IIS to enable specifying the content type in the AJAX call

[jQuery CORS Content-type OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320467/jquery-cors-content-type-options)

I have tested it without IIS content type header specified , and even if i add the crossDomain: true, I still get Jquery error complaining about CORS

Answer (score 1):

If it works fine from the same domain, you will need to enable CORS in that case, and your ajax call will include

`crossDomain: true,
 dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json",`

To enable CORS take a look at the example [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors)